# Setting cursor position for contenteditable html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, caret, cursor-position

I'm trying to set the cursor position in a contenteditable html div
But the error: `IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount`

Im working on a transliteration tool for contenteditable area.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5pzbtzc9/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#editable').click(function () {

            var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
            var start = range.anchorOffset; 
            var end = range.focusOffset;
            var element = document.getElementById('editable');
         var selection = document.getSelection();
         var newrange = document.createRange();
         newrange.setStart(element.firstChild, start);
         newrange.setEnd(element.firstChild, end);
         selection.removeAllRanges();
         selection.addRange(newrange);
    });

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="editable" id="editable" class="thumbnail value" contenteditable="true" style="width:500px;border:3px solid #ddd;padding:10px;margin:0 auto;">
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</h2> 
<p>Sedut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>
<p>tTotam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur</p>
<p><strong>Magni dolores eos qui ratione</strong> voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
<p>Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur</p>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to set the cursor inside editable div?

Comment: @Novice
Literally, I want to set at where it was.
Im doing some character replacement for a transliteration tool. where english text 'hum' is transliterated to 'हम' (say). As both character lengths are different, I will calculate the string length replaced, may be one position less or greater and set the cursor position at the end of the replaced character to continue typing.

I could achive this for textarea, but not sure how on contenteditable